# Find spectrum of the operator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I need some help to find point spectrum, residual spectrum, continuous spectrum and for this problem.

Let $\theta \in\mathbb{C}$. On the complex space $L^2[-1,1]$ consider the operator

$Au=v,$ where $v(x)=xu(x)+\theta \int^1_{-1} u(s)ds $.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried anything and can share that so users can provide feedback and guidance? Regards

Comment: I just really hope someone can help me solve this so I will have an example for my other problems.